# How to send PUT and DELETE forms in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I've been struggling with this question for a while, read a bunch of articles like:

[Razor Pages AJAX FORM](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/form-post)

[MSDN ASP.NET Core RESTfull Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)

And didn't grasp a proper way.

In my current project I have:

1. Form in my view:

```html
<form method="delete" asp-route="ProductCatalogSingle">
    <input hidden type="number" name="Id" value="@Model.Id" />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

2. Which is must send Delete request to my action:

```cs
// Controller have [Route("product-catalog")] attribute 

[HttpDelete("product", Name = "ProductCatalogSingle")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteSingleItem(int id)
{
    // business-logic part responsible for data managment
    await logic.RemoveDataModelAsync(new ProductCatalog { Id = id });
    return RedirectToRoute("ProductCatalogAll");
}

// other action with same route, but different method
[HttpGet("product", Name = "ProductCatalogSingle")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SingleItem(int id)
{...}
```

In default setup it doesn't working - instead it loads Get action.

So I tried a bunch of things:

1. Using Fetch API, with both `"/product-catalog/product"` and `"@Url.Link("ProductCatalogSingle", null)"` instead of `url`:

```js
@section scripts{
    <script>
        document.forms[0].onsubmit = () => {
            let formData = new FormData(document.forms[0]);
            fetch(url, {
                method: "DELETE",
                body: new URLSearchParams(formData)
            })
                .then(() => {
                    alert('Deleted using Fetch');
                });
            return true;
        };
    </script>
```

I receive alert notification, but request is didn't get sended.

2. Using AJAX unbostuctive:

```html
@section scripts{
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
}

<form method="delete" asp-route="ProductCatalogSingle" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="delete">
    <input hidden type="number" name="productId" value="@item.ProductId" />
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

3. Plain JQuery AJAX

```js
@section scripts{
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#submit').on('click', function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "DELETE",
                url: '/product-catalog/product?id=4001'
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

4. Changing IIS Express Server variables, like [IIS Express FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-faq) states

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" ... verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE"
```

None of this worked.